# Xed not installing

Tags: text-editor

Just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Trying to install Xed but get the following message:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/xapps/ubuntu focal Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/xapps/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Help!

Comment: No packages for 20.04 in that PPA. Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the information provided when you add the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:embrosyn/xapps
 This PPA contains builds of X-Apps for Ubuntu. X-Apps are a bunch of GTK3 DE-agnostic applications that are not so tightly tied to a particular distribution or DE as their ancestors (forkees) might be, developed by the Linux Mint crew:
* pix (image management application based on gThumb)
* xed (text editor based on Pluma),
* xplayer (media player based on Totem),
* xviewer (image viewer based on Eye of GNOME), and
* xreader (document reader based on Atril)

When nothing goes horribly wrong, this PPA should have the same packaging tempo and distribution series set as my Cinnamon PPA - the latest long-term support (LTS) and short-term (STS) releases, which currently means:
* Ubuntu 18.04, Bionic Beaver (bionic) [LTS],
* Ubuntu 19.04, Disco Dingo (disco) [STS].
```